# How to search near by places from marker's location?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

My location changes on basis of intent provided by another activity and it works fine that shows that location which i want from `LatitudeDegree` and `LongitudeDegree`. Now i want to show its near by places on user choice.like if he type ATM then near by ATM should be shown and etc..

This my code from which i got location and i tried to use place picker but i do not know whether i am right and how should i use.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private String mAirportName;
    private int mLatitudeDegree;
    private int mLongitudeDegree;
    private int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        Intent newIntent = getIntent();
        mAirportName = newIntent.getStringExtra("airportName");
        mLatitudeDegree = newIntent.getIntExtra("latDegree", 200);
        mLongitudeDegree = newIntent.getIntExtra("lngDegree", 201);

        /*PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

        try {
            startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker and move the camera
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLatitudeDegree, mLongitudeDegree);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(mAirportName));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(5));
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);
                String toastMsg = String.format("Place: %s", place.getName());
                Toast.makeText(this, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have that lat lng of those near items ?

Comment: LatitudeDegree and LongitudeDegree is nothing but my lat lng

Comment: If you want to display other positions like ATM you need those places lat lng as well

Comment: lat lng is for that city location which i have to search from my requirement and then after getting that location i have to search its near by places

Comment: i dont have  places lat lng

Comment: Then how can you show them :P

Comment: i did search on place picker it shows near by item itself

Comment: so i just wondering in my case how  to use it

Answer (score 0):

If you have **lat** **lang** of nearby items then use **Marker** and mark them. If you don't have then you need to buy such **APIs** or create your own **database** or try to search if there is open **APIs** are available.

Answer (score 0):

If you have other place(eg: Textile shop) location longitude and latitude you can use this method to check the distance between user and location ;

```
 public double callDistanceToMethod(LatLng latLngStartPosition, LatLng latLngEndPosition) {

        Location endLocation = new Location("EndPosition");
        endLocation.setLatitude(latLngEndPosition.latitude);
        endLocation.setLongitude(latLngEndPosition.longitude);

        Location startLocation = new Location("StartPosition");
        startLocation.setLatitude(latLngStartPosition.latitude);
        startLocation.setLongitude(latLngStartPosition.longitude);


        double distance = startLocation.distanceTo(endLocation);
        System.out.println("Hello Distance**--->" + distance);
        return distance;
    }
```

call this method like below (will return in meters)

```
Double distanceBetweenTwoLocations = callDistanceToMethod(startCoordinatesInLatLng, endCoordinatesInLatLng);
```

If you want now you can use a if condition

```
if(distanceBetweenTwoLocations <100){
// ok user is almost there in 100 meter range
// display an alert , send a push notification or anything 


}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer: if you hold your nearby placesin a list or in a database, you can findout the nearest places by following algorithm:

```
distancefaktor = ((currentlat-listitem_lat)*(currentlat-listitem_lat)+(currentlon-listitem_lon)*(currentlon*listitem_lon))
```

then sort the list by distancefaktor and take i.E. first 10 items.

I saw very late, you are working on a google map. In that case you have to use the google api to get nearby places:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search?hl=de